# Why is my json array showing an error when validating?

Tags: javascript, json, arraylist

Hi all and happy holidays first off. So I am still on a major learning curve so please bear with me. I have creates a json array of albums to call for use in javacript but every time I add a new album I get an error when checking on the "JSONLint - The JSON Validator" site. I can't figure out what the problem is...

```js
var albumData =[
  {
   "album":
    { 
     "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx1.png",
     "artist": "Gen1artist",
     "name": "Gen1name",
     "release":"released 2017",
     "tracks":
     [
      {
       "TrackNumber": "1.",
       "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
       "song":"Gen1Track1",
       "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
       "duration":"2:47"
      },
      {
       "TrackNumber": "2.",
       "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
       "song":"Gen1Track2",
       "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
       "duration":"2:47"
      },
      {
       "TrackNumber": "3.",
       "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
       "song":"Gen1Track1",
       "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
       "duration":"2:47"
      }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "album":
    { 
     "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx2.png",
     "artist": "Gen2artist",
     "name": "Gen2name",
     "release":"released 2020",
     "tracks":
     [
      {
       "TrackNumber": "1.",
       "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
       "song":"Gen2Track1",
       "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
       "duration":"2:47"
      },
      {
       "TrackNumber": "2.",
       "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
       "song":"Gen2Track2",
       "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
       "duration":"2:47"
      },
      {
       "TrackNumber": "3.",
       "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
       "song":"Gen2Track1",
       "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
       "duration":"2:47"
      }
    ]
   }
  }]
```

Comment: What you have is a valid JSON. What do you mean by "add a new album"?

Comment: I checked your JSON object with https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer and it looks okay.

Comment: I have 2 examples of albums. The imageUrl, artist, name, release and tracks are different for all of them. I need to be able to do a ++ ect when call the info later but my array will not validate more than one album.

Comment: I use each for a slide Index and push each album with dots and next-prev buttons

Comment: Thx Abdullah, but I get an error on your site example:E2 ->Error: Parse error on line 1: Parse error on line ^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to validating your JSON in JSONlint please check you are copy your json correctly or not just copy the json start with value inside the square braces `[{...}]` , do not copy the json with variable `var albumData=`

and if you want to add a new album inside array please use below method to add new album

```
albumData.push({
            "album":
                {   
                    "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx1.png",
                    "artist": "Gen1artist",
                    "name": "Gen1name",
                    "release":"released 2017",
                    "tracks":
                    [
                        {
                            "TrackNumber": "1.",
                            "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
                            "song":"Gen1Track1",
                            "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
                            "duration":"2:47"
                        },
                        {
                            "TrackNumber": "2.",
                            "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
                            "song":"Gen1Track2",
                            "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
                            "duration":"2:47"
                        },
                        {
                            "TrackNumber": "3.",
                            "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
                            "song":"Gen1Track1",
                            "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
                            "duration":"2:47"
                        }
                ]
            }
        })
```

and if your `albumData` is an string json then before adding value you need to pasre it first to the javascript object.

```
albumData = JSON.parse(albumData);
```

and then add new album to is using `albumData.push({..})`

hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Hi Bhargav, thx..I think I might be going about this in the wrong way. I'm not quite sure how to incorporate the push method with how my html and javascript are written. I think I'm going to post a newer question that addresses how I've written the javascript part which has parts that add divs when needed. I hope this makes sense. lol. I am very new and trying to learn the best most effecitive way but fear my skills are lacking.

Comment: Anytime, and don't worry mistakes will sharp your skills defiantly